# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected end of file - PHP 5

Tags: wordpress, parsing, syntax

I've debugged my index file and filtered out my code.  Turns out that if I use the following code, the site returns an "unexpected end of file" error.  If I remove it, the site appears with no errors.  So I'm not sure if I am missing any syntax code or if there is a typo.

```
 <?php

 // The Query
 query_posts( 'cat=9614&posts_per_page=5&tag=review' );

 // The Loop
 while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
 ?>
 <li>
 <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
 </li>
 <?
 endwhile;

 // Reset Query
 wp_reset_query();

 ?>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `<?php` instead of `<?`

```
<?php

 // The Query
 query_posts( 'cat=9614&posts_per_page=5&tag=review' );

 // The Loop
 while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
 ?>
 <li>
 <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
 </li>
 <?php // error is here
 endwhile;

 // Reset Query
 wp_reset_query();

 ?>
```

Comment: Thanks bud! 85-90% of my mistakes in code are small/minor/hidden errors.  Site is back up now with the revised code.